# How can I get the refresh rate via ADB?

Tags: adb, screen

How can I use ADB to get the refresh rate of a device's screen?

For context: I'm working on a python script that is going to display how many dropped frames occurred while it was measuring. In order to calculate that, I need to know the expected refresh rate of the device's screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the refresh rate through this command:

```
adb shell dumpsys display | grep -i mphys | cut -d ',' -f 2
```

Note that `dumpsys display` mentions refresh rate at other places too.

Derived from chr0m4k3y's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527459/android-device-screen-size/26185910#26185910) on Stack Overflow.